# simplify object transformation with javascript higher order functions

Tags: javascript, undefined, transformation, higher-order-functions

Goal: I am trying to reduce complexity of my object transformation. I've been told to use higher order functions to reduce the complexity. I am mainly looking at the for block of code to simplify but any other pointers or help would be appreciated.

Problem: I do not see a clear way to simplify this even with higher order functions.

Note: that I am not guaranteed to have all the fields so i need to guard against key undefined. That is why i am doing (model) => model.key to only read property if i verify the key is there.

model:

```
{ 
  "origName1": "val1",
  "origName2": "val2",
  "origName3": "val3",<-- this key value is not always present
  "origName4": "val4"  
}
```

my transformation obj:

```
let transFormObj = {};
transFormObj.origName1= {'newKey': 'newName1', 'value': (model) => model.origName1};
transFormObj.origName2= {'newKey': 'newName2', 'value': (model) => model.origName2};
transFormObj.origName3= {'newKey': 'newName3', 'value': (model) => model.origName3};
transFormObj.origName4= {'newKey': {parentKey: 'newObj', childKey: 'newName4'}, 'value': (model) => model.origName4};
```

The for block i am focusing on:

```
 let returnObj = {}
        for(let key in model) {
            if(key in transFormObj) {
                // is nested object?
                if(typeof(transFormObj[key].newKey) === 'object') {
                    // if parent key doesn't exist create else keep it the same
                    returnObj[transFormObj[key].newKey.parentKey] = returnObj[transFormObj[key].newKey.parentKey] || {};
                    returnObj[transFormObj[key].newKey.parentKey][transFormObj[key].newKey.childKey] = transFormObj[key].value(model);
                } else {
                returnObj[transFormObj[key].newKey] = transFormObj[key].value(model);}
            }
        }
```

expected output object:

```
{ 
      "newName1": "val1",
      "newName2": "val2",
      "newName3": "val3",
      "newObj": {"newName4" :"val4"}  
    }
```

Comment: Is the `transFormObj` hard-coded, or is it generated from an input of some sort? Seems a bit odd as is

Comment: it is hard coded. Originally it was just a json object to map to the new object, but since i can't guarantee that all the attributes will be there I started to make the object as you see it so I could kinda do lazy load to avoid accessing undefined fields

Comment: Sounds like you just need a table that maps original key names to new ones, and then enumerate the properties of the object to be transformed, checking to see if the current key is in the table.

Comment: @Codyj110. you are looking for  reduce. use Object.keys(model).reduce and write your logic to map to the desired object.

Answer (score 0):

This is the furthest i could simplify.
filter got rid of an if.
reduce got rid of the for, and returnObj variable;

```
return Object.keys(model)
        .filter(key => key in transFormObj)
        .reduce((rObj, key) =>
        {
            let newKey = transFormObj[key].newKey;
            if(isObject(newKey)) {
                let parentKey =  newKey.parentKey;
                let childKey = newKey.childKey;
                rObj[parentKey] = rObj[parentKey] || {};
                rObj[parentKey][childKey] = transFormObj[key].value(model);
            } else {
                rObj[newKey] = transFormObj[key].value(model);
            }
            return rObj;
        }, {}
        );
```